# Приложение вылетает после вывода текста на TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:text="ВЫВОД"
            android:id="@+id/rezult_ravno"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="ВЫВОД"
            android:onClick="rezult"/>




public void rezult()
{
    TextView rezultText = findViewById(R.id.rezult_ravno);
    rezultText.setText("Вылетает");
}
```

После нажатия кнопки Button, выполняющей метод rezult() программа вылетает(

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.azeroth.calculator, PID: 10272
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method rezult(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4802)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20101)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

Comment: Читаем логи, если непонятно, что написано, то копируем их в вопрос.

Comment: Я мягко выражаясь новичок :P Если это то, что имелось ввиду, то вот)

Comment: Покажите код обработчика нажатия

Answer (score 3):

Вижу, что вы подвесили метод `result` в xml (`android:onClick="rezult"`). Если вы подвешиваете метод таким образом, то метод result кажется должен быть таким:

```
public void rezult(View view) {
    TextView rezultText = findViewById(R.id.rezult_ravno);
    rezultText.setText("Вылетает");
}
```

Т.е. на вход принимать параметр View. Так делать не рекомендуется, а и не удобно это. Удалите эту строчку из xml. В методе onCreate на кнопку подвесьте обработчик с вашим методом, вот вам пример на русском https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/16-urok-9-obrabotchiki-sobytij-na-primere-button.html Посмотрите так же уркои по binding и по kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изменить `TextView rezultText = findViewById(R.id.rezult_ravno);`

на `TextView rezultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezult_ravno);`

Нужно быть немного внимательнее))

Comment: )) не нужно так изменять `(TextView)` и любые вью элементы уже не нужно так указывать.